# Java - OpenCv - JavaCv

Tags: java, eclipse, computer-vision, javacv

I'm trying to get some images from a camera using Java,
but I'm running into a few issues; any help would be appreciated!

Code Below:

[image]

Error Log:

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_highgui in java.library.path
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
                at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:711)
                at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:586)
                at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:540)
                at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:79)
                at Main.main(Main.java:10)
            Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp21202077019496\jniopencv_highgui.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
                at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
                at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:700)
                ... 4 more
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21135080/installation-of-javacv

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my problem was to download:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/javacv/downloads

javacv-0.7-cppjars.zip 
javacv-0.7-src.zip

and to add them all as external jars, i just didn't add the jars from javacv-0.7-cppjars.zip